# laravel merge all arrays into one

Tags: php, laravel

I have search function where it searches into several model and get results back, now i would like to have all those model results into one variable so i can use only one variable in my blade.

**How can i do that?**

## Code

```
public function results(Request $request) {
    $q = $request->input('q');

    $products = Product::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $posts = Post::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $pages = Page::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $tags = Tag::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $jobs = Job::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $categories = Category::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $listings = Listing::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $portfolios = Portfolio::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $services = Service::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    return view('front.pages.search', compact('products', 'q', 'pages', 'posts', 'tags', 'jobs', 'categories', 'listings', 'portfolios', 'services'))->withQuery($q);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the results in an assoc array instead of separate variables.

```
public function results(Request $request) {

    $q = $request->input('q');

    $result = [];

    $result['products'] = Product::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
    ->paginate(9);

    $result['posts'] = Post::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
    ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
    ->paginate(9);

    $result['pages'] = Page::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['tags'] = Tag::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['jobs'] = Job::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['categories'] = Category::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['listings'] = Listing::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['portfolios'] = Portfolio::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);

    $result['services'] = Service::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
       ->paginate(9);

    return view('front.pages.search', compact($result))->withQuery($q);
```

}

Comment: can i have them all under result array? let say `results[ posts[],products[],etc[]. ]`

Comment: yes but at the firat i was just getting 9 arrays then i changed your code now i have one array and 9 arrays under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one make codes cleaner,

First defined the array of all your models names.

Secondly, loop this models' names, concat with namespace then query on it.

Thirdly, convert the model name to plural and camel form as key, and put the result in with this key.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...

$namespace = 'App\\';
$models = ["Product", "Post", "Page", "Tag", "Job", "Category", "Listing", "Portfolio", "Service"];

$data = array();
foreach($models as $model) {
    $key = str_plural(Str::camel($model));
    $data[$key] = ($namespace.$model)::where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$q}%")
        ->paginate(9);
}
dd($data);
```